# Debian error logs on boot

Tags: debian, boot

I get the following error logs when booting Debian, but they do not seem to be causing any problems once booted into the system. Should I be concerned?

```
ACPI Error : Namespace lookup failure AE not found

Failed to start raise network services

nouveau DRM : Pointer to TMDS table invalid.

nouveau DRM : Pointed to flat panel table invalid.
```

Comment: Is your computer BIOS up to date ?

Comment: Oh probably not. Ill try it and update here. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasGros I updated my BIOS and faced the same error logs on booting.

Comment: Last time I encountered this error was when using a laptop with a NVIDIA GPU, Optimus technology and the Nouveau driver. Does it sounds like your computer ?

Comment: @ThomasGros I am not using Optimus Technology but the rest fit perfectly.